# Select distinct to remove duplicate rows?

Tags: mysql, greatest-n-per-group

I have a forum with a Posts and Comments table. I'd like to sort by recent comments:

```
select distinct(p.id)
    ,p.title
    ,c.id 
from Posts as p
    ,Comments as c 
where c.post_id = p.id 
order by c.id DESC 
LIMIT 50;
```

However I get a row for every comment.  I know I want to loop through the most recent comments  and grab the first 50 unique posts.  I just can't translate that to SQL.

Comment: What are you looking to return? Do you want a single row per Post, with every comment in its own row? Also, what are you trying to use this code for?

Comment: Sorting posts by recent comments. I want to loop through the most recent comments and grab the first 50 unique posts.

Comment: do u have date/time column in your db ?

Comment: You're making a classic mistake of SQL novices. `DISTINCT` does not apply to just one column, despite your use of parentheses around `(p.id)`. But `DISTINCT` always applies to *all* the columns in the select-list. That is, if any column has a different value, the whole row counts as a distinct row.

Comment: @Mark have a look at my updated answer

Comment: I updated my answer too, with one that should be more scalable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution without subqueries:

```
SELECT p.id, p.title, MAX(c.id) AS comment_id
FROM Posts AS p
JOIN Comments AS c 
  ON c.post_id = p.id
GROUP BY p.id
ORDER by comment_id DESC 
LIMIT 50
```

This way may be a bit faster and more scalable despite the subquery because it can optimize on the limit clause:

```
SELECT p.id, p.title, MAX(c.id) AS comment_id
FROM Posts p
JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT c.post_id FROM Comments c ORDER BY c.id DESC LIMIT 50) t
ON t.post_id = p.id
JOIN Comments c
  ON c.post_id = p.id
GROUP BY p.id
ORDER BY comment_id DESC
```

Make sure there is an index on `Comments(post_id)`.

Comment: Great that does it - needed the index on post_id

Comment: @Mark, unfortunately, EXPLAIN doesn't reflect the LIMIT optimization. It's one you have to run. Put `SQL_NO_CACHE` after the `SELECT` when testing the speed to prevent the query cache from affecting your tests.

Answer (score 0):

You can do so ,by getting the max of comment id for each post group and join with your posts table then do order by comments id

```
select p.id, p.title, c.id 
from 
Posts as p
JOIN 
(select max(id) id ,post_id 
  from Comments group by 
  post_id LIMIT 50) c
   ON(c.post_id = p.id)
 order by c.id DESC;
```

Note above query will give the recent comment id only for each post group you can't use `*` in subquery to fetch the entire row for a comment this means this will not give the recent comment for each post if you select all in subquery

**Edit** this query will use only one join with limit in inner query so only 50 post's recent comment will be joined and its the inner join so it will take care to returned only associated posts,moreover the performance can be clear if you see the explain plan for your quesries

Answer (score 0):

```
select p.id
    ,p.title
    ,c.id 
from Posts as p
    ,Comments as c 
where c.post_id in (
                    select distict (id) 
                    from posts
                   )
order by c.id desc 
limit 50;
```

Thanks, Gaurav

Comment: You will surely need group by in case of post wise top 50